# Time complexity of Rabin-Karp algorithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, string-matching

> **$n$ : length of text T**
>
> **$m$ : length of pattern P**

When I study Rabin-Karp algorithm, I learned the best case of this algorithm is $\theta(n-m+1)$. Because if a hashed number is too small to modulo by some other number.

But when I'm talking with my friends about this best complexity, I was very curios that does above theta notation can be represented by $\theta(n)$ if $n$ is asymptotic to infinity?

First time, it was reasonable to me that $\theta(n)=\theta(n-m+1)$ is correct because it is asymptotic notation. But if $m$ is always $n-1$, can we use $\theta(n)$ in this situation? I'm confusing about notation concept and what I'm curious is below question.

> What is the right time complexity notation of Rabin-Karp algorithm?
>
> $\theta(n)$ or $\theta(n-m+1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The running time you quote isn't correct. If $n = m$ then it takes $\Omega(n)$ to verify that $T = P$. The best case running time of *any* string matching algorithm is $\Omega(m)$, since this is how long it takes to verify a match. Perhaps you are disregarding the time it takes to compute the hashes.

Ignoring all of this, let us suppose that we are considering an algorithm whose running time is $\Theta(n-m+1)$, where $m \leq n$ are two parameters. As your example makes clear, this is *not* the same as $\Theta(n)$, since if $m$ is close to $n$ then $n-m+1$ is much smaller than $n$. Generally speaking, an asymptotic expression depending on two parameters cannot be reduced to an asymptotic expression depending on only one of them.

In practice, often $m$ is itself a known function of $n$, and this can be used to reduce $\Theta(n-m+1)$ to an asymptotic expression depending on a single parameter. For example, if $m = n/2$ then $\Theta(n-m+1) = \Theta(n)$, whereas if $m = n$, then $\Theta(n-m+1) = \Theta(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Rabin-Karp algo consists of two steps:

- hash first m symbols of input and the pattern, which takes $\theta(m)$
- check first n-m+1 positions of the file comparing hashes of next m chars at each position to the pattern hash, which takes $\theta(n-m+1)$

Most probably, your source mentioned only the second step complexity.